# three dot button in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am beginer to oracle ADF and I want to know, is there any component to create three dot menubar or button in oracle ADF as below? I have checked the docs and browsed but have no luck.

[image]

Appreciated any help on this.

Comment: Provide a minimal working sample which you have tried. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TheGaME to be honest, I am looking for the component that can help me to start.

Comment: What is your ADF version? If your using JDeveloper then what is the version?

Comment: @TheGaME using the jdev version 11.1 and ADF also 11 version

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry, but all I see is an image with three black dots. Without a detailed description of what this button should do exactly, a simple button with an icon showing three dots will do.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code and let me know if it works.

```
 <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl1">
  <af:gridRow id="gr1">
    <af:gridCell id="gc1">
     <af:commandButton text="Button 1" id="cb1" styleClass="circular" inlineStyle="height:30px;width:30px;background-color:Black;"/>
</af:gridCell>
    <af:gridCell id="gc2">
     <af:commandButton text="Button 2" id="cb2" styleClass="circular" inlineStyle="height:30px;width:30px;background-color:Black;"/>
</af:gridCell>
    <af:gridCell id="gc3">
     <af:commandButton text="Button 3" id="cb3" styleClass="circular" inlineStyle="height:30px;width:30px;background-color:Black;"/>
</af:gridCell>
  </af:gridRow>
</af:panelGridLayout>
```

Add the following style to your stylesheet.

```
.circular {
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```